# Finding lagged time series effects

Tags: time-series, lags, intervention-analysis

I have a time series with the number of customers and discounts. I suspect that the percentage of discount has a postponed effect.

I tried just lagging the variable and calculating the correlation, but looking for other suggestions to increase my knowledge about this kind of problem.

My data set

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2022-01-01"), "month")
discount <- c(0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1)

data.frame(1:12, discount, (1:12) + 6)
customers <- c(10000, 15000, 7000, 7000, 17500, 7000, 6500, 7000, 7000, 8000, 8000, 8000)

df <- data.frame(date = date, discount = rep(discount, length.out = 145), n_customers = rep(customers, length.out = 145))

cors <- c()

for(i in 0:12){
  
  
  cors[[i + 1]] <- cor(df$discount, lead(df$n_customers, i), use = "complete.obs")
  
  
}

cors
```

Comment: Did you check the cross-correlation function (CCF)?

Comment: @FelixPhl No, never heard of it, will look into it. Thanks